# What are the functions for the wires beige, green, orange, black, yellow, red; when wiring up a thermostat for One's central A/C

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I want to change (digital) thermostat and replace it with (non-digital) non- programmable  thermostat.  The thermostat I'm wanting to use only has spots for 4 wires. Which leaves 2 remaining wires.  Which are a must?

Comment: Shoot us a photo of the old wiring.  Also model numbers of old and new.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace end?  Also, are you replacing a thermostat that's known-bad/malfunctioning, or trying to correct an issue with the system as a whole?